# usbip: problem getting device attributes: No such file or directory

Tags: usb

I try to use an ftdi rs232/usb adapter over ethernet. It's connected to my raspberry pi.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ usbip list -l
Local USB devices
=================
- busid 1-1 (0424:9512)
    1-1:1.0 -> hub

- busid 1-1.1 (0424:ec00)
    1-1.1:1.0 -> smsc95xx

- busid 1-1.2 (0403:6001)
    1-1.2:1.0 -> unknown

- busid 1-1.3 (7392:7811)
    1-1.3:1.0 -> rtl8192cu

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo usbip -d bind -b 1-1.2:1.0
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip.c:134:[run_command] running command: `bind'
usbip: debug: /build/linux-tools-TqR1ks/linux-tools-3.2.17/drivers/staging/usbip/userspace/src/usbip_bind.c:143:[unbind_other] problem getting device attributes: No such file or directory
usbip: error: could not unbind driver from device on busid 1-1.2:1.0
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

The state above is after `rmmod ftdi_sio`, same problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Note that bus id for bind parameter is in your case `1-1.2`.

Error that you get usually means that you didn't run `usbipd`:

```
sudo usbipd -D
```

If you are unable to run usbip daemon you probably need `usb-core.ko` and `usb-host` kernel module.

Full instruction how to get through `usbip` setting process you can find in my blog post. Second link point to updated version of post:

- [Linux, RPi and USB Over IP](http://blog.3mdeb.com/2014/08/18/linux-rpi-and-usb-over-ip/)
- [Linux, RPi and USB Over IP updated](http://blog.3mdeb.com/2015/10/27/linux/)

Comment: Now, it shows a 404 message...

Comment: @davidbaumann Thanks for pointing out - link fixed.